# Show that $u(x)=\ln\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\right)$ is in $W^{1,n}(U)$, where $U=B(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, polar-coordinates

The entire problem statement is:

Let $n>1$ and let $U=B(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $u:U\to\mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$u(x)=\ln\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\right)$$ is in $W^{1,n}(U).$

My attempt at the proof is as follows:

To show that $u\in W^{1,n}(U)$ it suffices to show that $|Du|\in L^{n}(U)$. Consider
$$u_{x_i}=\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}|x|^{-2}\frac{x_i}{|x|},$$
which simplifies to,
$$u_{x_i}=\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}.$$
Thus,
$$|Du|=\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}\frac{1}{|x|^2}$$
which can be manipulated to,
$$|Du|=\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}\frac{1}{1+|x|}\frac{1}{|x|}.$$

Moreover, since $U=B(0,1)$ we can bound the second term from above which gives,
$$|Du|\leq\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}\frac{1}{|x|}$$

Thus, we can instead show that
$$\int_U\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}\frac{1}{|x|}\right)^n<\infty.$$

Converting this into polar coordinates we have with $r=|x|$,
$$\int_0^R\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)}\frac{1}{r}\right)^n\,dSdr=\int_0^R\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)}\frac{1}{r}\right)^n\int_{\partial B(0,r)}dSdr$$
Note that $\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\,dS=n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}$, which is the surface area of $B(0,r)$. Thus, we have then
$$n\alpha(n)\int_0^R\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)}\frac{1}{r}\right)^nr^{n-1}\,dr=n\alpha(n)\int_0^R\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)}\right)^n\frac{1}{r}\,dr$$

And so this is where I get stuck in the problem, since I don't how I can evaluate that last integral to show it's finite.

Thank you for any help or feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the problem should be
$u(x):=\ln\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\right) $
but not 
$u(x)=\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+|x|}\right)\right)$
as you stated.

Next, we have

$$ \partial_i u(x) =   - \frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{|x|})}\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}$$
Notice that 
$$ \frac{x_i}{|x|^3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}=\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}\frac{|x|}{|x|+1}=\frac{x_i}{|x|^2}\frac{1}{|x|+1}  $$
and the term
$$  \frac{1}{|x|+1}$$
does not matter
and the term 
$$\left\lvert\frac{x_i}{|x|^2}\right\rvert=\frac{1}{|x|}$$
Hence we have
$$ |\nabla u| \approx -\frac{1}{\ln|x|}\frac{1}{|x|}$$
and the integrand, after change to polar, is
$$ -\frac{1}{\ln^n r}\frac{1}{r} $$
and it is integrable since $n>1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did you get the approximation of $|\nabla u|$ by considering $|x|$ in $\frac{1}{\ln(|x|+1)-\ln(|x|)}\frac{1}{|x|}$ near zero, since at $|x|=1$ we get $\frac{1}{\ln(2)}$?

Comment: No, just notice that $\ln(1+1/|x|)$ is close to $\ln(1/|x|)$ as $|x|$ goes to $0$

Comment: How does the $n$ appear when you coverted to polar coordinates?

Comment: @dragon you are computing $L^n$ norm right?

Comment: I see, so you just raised your $|\nabla u|$ to the power of $n$ so that your resulting function belongs to $L^n$. But now I'm still trying to see how you approximated $$|\nabla u|= \left| \frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{|x|})}\frac{x}{|x|^3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{|x|}} \right|$$ to $-\frac 1{\ln|x|} \frac 1{|x|}$. Yes, I see the natural log approximation for $x$ close to $0$, but what about the $\frac 1{1+\frac 1{|x|}}$ for $x$ close to $0$?

Comment: @dragon I upgrade my answer

Comment: Why is it suffice to only prove that $Du \in L^n$? Shouldn't one prove that $u$ also belongs to $L^n$?

Comment: @Leo a quick answer is $u$ has lower order compare to $Du$. So, as long as $Du\in L^n$, $u\in L^2$ for sure.

Comment: @JumpJump Are you using a Inequality of the Sobolev type? To apply those wouldn't it be required to have that $u \in W^{1,n}_0$? Besides, don't we need $u$ to be in $L^n$ instead of $L^2$? Sorry if those are silly questions.

Comment: @Leo Ok. Forget about sobolev type inequality. Just following the above computation and prove that $u$ is $W^{1,n}$.

Comment: How do you get the estimate for $|\nabla u|$?

Comment: Also, I think one needs also to show that $\nabla u$ is indeed the weak derivative of $u$ due to the existence of example that $u$ could be differentiable almost everywhere without being weakly differentiable.

Comment: the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{r \ln(r)^n} dr$ does not converge for any power of $n > 1$

Comment: @user770687 Yes, but it does converge for any integration limit $[0, a]$ for $0 < a < 1$. And since both $u$ and $\nabla u$ themselves are integrable near $1$, there is no problem.