# Prove $u=\ln\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\in W^{1,n}(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Prove that for $n>1$,the non-bounded function $u=\ln\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\in W^{1,n}(\Omega)$,Here $\Omega=B(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$

I think we have to prove that
$$ \int_{B(0,1)}\left|\ln\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\right|^{n} dx<\infty,$$ 
and 
$$ \int_{B(0,1)}\left|D\ln\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\right|^{n} dx<\infty,$$
but it hard for me to compute these integrates.

Comment: What have you tried? where is this problem from? What is $W$? With 600+ rep, you could ask better questions.

Comment: $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is a classical notation for a Sobolev space

Comment: Please try  to search your question before asking it. For instance, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036001/show-that-ux-ln-left-ln-left1-frac1x-right-right-is-in-w1-n/1036121#1036121

Answer (score 4):

First, we need to show that  $u \in L^n(\Omega)$. You can show by a change of variable that

$$\int_\Omega |\ln \ln (1 + \frac{1}{|x|})|^n dx \leq C \int_0^1 |\ln \ln (1 + \frac{1}{r})|^n r^{n-1} dr$$

The function $|\ln \ln (1 + \frac{1}{r})|^n r^{n-1}$ is continuous on $]0,1]$, so the only problem may be on 0. But we have that for r smaller than 1/e

$$1 < \ln (1 + \frac{1}{r}) < \frac{1}{r}$$

Hence

$$0<|\ln \ln (1 + \frac{1}{r})|^n < \ln(\frac{1}{r})^n$$

So

$$0 < |\ln \ln (1 + \frac{1}{r})|^n r^{n-1} < \ln(\frac{1}{r})^nr^{n-1}$$ and this converge to 0. So the function is bounded near 0, and integrable near 0

Then for $\nabla f$, you can see that it's differentiable in the classical sense, so computing $\nabla f$ is not too problematic. If I'm not mistaken,

$$\partial_i f(x) = \frac{x_i}{|x|^2(1+|x|)\ln(1+\frac{1}{|x|})}$$

You get that

$$\int_{\Omega} \left( \partial_i f(x)\right)^n dx \leq \int_0^1 \left| \frac{r}{r^2(1+r)\ln(1+\frac{1}{r})} \right|^n r^{n-1} dr$$

$$= \int_0^1  \frac{r^{n-1}}{(r^2(1+r))^n } \frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{r})^n} dr  $$

Same thing, the only problem is on 0, but the function is positive, so we can take an equivalent

$$\frac{r^{2n-1}}{(r(1+r))^n \ln(1+\frac{1}{r})^n} \sim_0 \frac{1}{r\ln(1+\frac{1}{r})^n} $$

This can be show to be equivalent to

$$\sim_0 \frac{1}{r|\ln(r)|^n}$$

And this function is classically know to be integrable near 0 (looks for Bertrand integral if you don't know it)

Comment: $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{r \ln(r)^n} dr$ does not converge for $n > 1$