# The function $f \in W^{1,d} (\mathbb{R}^d)$ which is $f \notin L^\infty (\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Can we construct such $f \in W^{1,d} (\mathbb{R}^d)$ which is $f \notin L^\infty (\mathbb{R})$, for $d\ge2$? Tried several functions e.g. $f(x)=\exp(|x|), x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ over the $\Omega=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: |x|<r, \quad \text{for} \quad r>0\}$  but failed. Any idea, please?

Comment: When $d=1$ we cannot have such a function. I suspect that the same situation holds for any $d$.

Comment: Okay, do you have any idea for $d\ge 2$? It really hard to construct.

Comment: If memory serves me well, $\log\log(1+ 1/|x|)$ should do it (you can make it decay  when you're far away from 0 so that there are no concerns at infinity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $u(x)=\ln\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\right)$ is in $W^{1,n}(U)$, where $U=B(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036001/show-that-ux-ln-left-ln-left1-frac1x-right-right-is-in-w1-n)

Comment: (The questions are not exact duplicates but that answer does answer this question. I don't know if I'm using this "close vote" correctly, since there should be other different examples of $f$ that could be an answer here, but not there...)

Comment: Unfortunately $ln(ln(1+\frac{1}{|x|}))$ is not in $L^d(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Comment: @acreativename as mentioned this is not a problem at all (see my first comment)

Comment: Sorry your suggestion seems appropriate; do you have any idea how you would implement your suggestion ?

Comment: Thinking along your lines maybe $ln(ln(1+\frac{1}{|x|}))e^{-|x|^2}$ does the job.

Comment: That should work but its easier if you just use an extension operator (you can check Evans section 5.4 in the 2nd edition, it should also be somewhere in the 1st edition) @acreativename

Comment: Yeah that is much better